# saving at a database with encoding errors

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

The manual at php about mysql encoding is confusing.

MY chrome encoding is set at utf-8 but when it is saved at mysql database it is stored as iso-8859-1

At a web browser it shows:

```
I'm Done.
```

But when I see at phpmyadmin/getting the value thru mysql query what I get is:

```
 Iâ€™m Done.
```

Comment: You're storing UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1, that's where the `â€™` stuff comes from. Can you switch your database to UTF-8?

Comment: You need to set your MySQL tables to store data in UTF-8 ***and*** you need to set your MySQL connection to UTF-8. This has been asked a zillion times, search for appropriate keywords. Hint: `SET NAMES utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

this function  may help you
Please first make r&d on function than use

```
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
```